# Оформление заголовка с прямой речью

Tags: пунктуация, оформление-текста, названия

Здравствуйте! Помогите с оформлением заголовка, пожалуйста.

В заголовке типа **_слова автора:_прямая речь** последнюю можно не брать в кавычки, **начать большой буквы или с маленькой**.

Например:

**Иванов: Зима будет холодной**

или

**Минфин: зарплаты будут выше**

А как следует оформлять заголовки, если сначала следует прямая речь, а затем слова автора. Объясните на примере:

**"Улики сфабрикованы!": родственники задержанного полицейского не верят в правосудие**

Или:

**"Улики сфабрикованы", — родственники задержанного полицейского не верят в правосудие**

Буду также благодарна за примеры и разъяснения других возможных трудных случаев оформления заголовка. Нюансы, примеры, ссылки. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

При таком оформлении трудно понять, что это прямая речь, т.к. нет слов речи-мысли, вводящие прямую речь:  сказал, заявил, предложил,и т.д. Лучше переформулировать предложение,чтобы было ясно,что это прямая речь.

***Родственники задержанного полицейского не верят в правосудие!
"Улики сфабрикованы!"— заявляют они!***

Подробнее об оформлении заголовках, см.:  [Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168)

Comment: Считаю, что запятая после восклицательного знака совершенно лишняя. "Улики сфабрикованы!" — заявляют они!

Comment: @V.Lila,вы правы: запятая не ставится, если прямой речи следует вопросительный или восклицательный знак.